# How to get a frame by id on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using [onBeforeRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(object details) {...});
```

The details return

> frameId ( integer )

So I have the frame id, how can I retrieve the element frame from this id and access the `src`, `parentId`...?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please tell me, I won't be mad I will only be sad :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for your background page.  You probably don't care about the actual tab but rather want to associate header info with that tabId.  To do that, do the following:
1) create tabs container: "tabs = {}"
2) store details in that container: "tabs[details.id].details.push(details);"

That would look something like this:

```
tabs = {};

init=function(){
...
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(beforeRedirect, requestFilter, extraInfo);
...
}

beforeRedirect = function(details){
...
tabs[details.id].details.push(details);
...
}
```

You also have the option of chrome.tabs.query to hook into the actual tab.  If all you're wanting is to store header info, you probably wouldn't want to use this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, function(tab){
    var currentTab = tab[0];
    ...
```